# How to reflect changes, that was made in model at app server, in view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

everyone.

**The preamble.**
Let's look at this typical situation. Here's 3-tier application:

- WPF (or Silverlight, it doesn't matter) client, built upon MVVM;
- WCF service (application server);
- some RDBMS as storage.

Here's simple "order-order items" domain model:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Id { ... }
    [DataMember]
    public Decimal Total { ... }
    [DataMember]
    public Decimal Discount { ... }
    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<OrderItem> Items { ... }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class OrderItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Id { ... }
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { ... }
    [DataMember]
    public Decimal Price { ... }
    [DataMember]
    public Decimal Quantity { ... }
    [DataMember]
    public Order Order { ... }
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 OrderId { ... }
}
```

Properties Order.Id and OrderItem.Id is identity properties.
Properties Order.Total and Order.Discount is calculated properties.
Identity and calculated properties cannot be set at the client side - they must be set at the server, their values depend on server's logic. Also, app server can add new items to order (e. g. gifts), or modify quantity of the existing items (depending on the stock's state).

At the client side, this models is wrapped into corresponding view models:

```
public class OrderVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Order model;

    public OrderVM(Order model)
    {
        this.model = model;

        ...
    }

    public Int32 Id { ... }
    public Decimal Total { ... }
    public Decimal Discount { ... }
    public ObservableCollection<OrderItemVM> Items { ... }

    // ...
}

public class OrderItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public OrderItemVM(OrderItem model)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Int32 Id { ... }
    public String Name { ... }
    public Decimal Price { ... }
    public Decimal Quantity { ... }

    // ...
}
```

Model classes implements INPC, so, if model was changed outside of UI, view model will reflect this changes.

Application server is a WCF service. Here's it's contract:

```
[ServiceContract(...)]
public interface OrderService
{
    [OperationContract(...)]
    Order SaveOrder(Order order);
}
```

What OrderService.SaveOrder does: it receives order, retrieves identity and calculated properties, changes order (add or change items), and returns the same order back to the client.

OrderVM has a command "Apply". View that displays OrderVM, has a button, which is bound to OrderVM.Apply.
OrderVM.Apply must call OrderService.SaveOrder:

```
void ApplyExecute()
{
    var savedOrder = ordersService.SaveOrder(model);
}
```

**The question.**
From the CLR's point of view, source order (field OrderVM.order) and savedOrder is different objects.
I need to reflect changes, which present in savedOrder now, so they must be displayed to user.

Is there any common approaches or the best practice, how to do this?
Please, take into consideration that:

- command is "Apply", not "Save and close": user must stay in the same view of the same order;
- this is simple model, real models will be more complex.

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to either have to throw out all your items (easiest option, though slow to execute), or update them.  If you update them, you're going to have to apply a diff to determine which items up add/remove/update.  Or you can cheat and apply your local changes directly to your view and ignore what is on the server unless the user explicitly refreshes.  It is up to you which best matches your requirements (usability/perf/reflecting latest server state), and which is within your available cost to implement.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `model = ordersServer.SaveOrder(model)`?

Comment: @Rachel, UI will ignore this - somebody have to raise PropertyChanged event.

Comment: @Merlyn: throwing out seems to be too expensive - e. g., the server has updated only one scalar property, and the client have to repaint complex view completely.

Comment: @Dennis: Sounds like you'll either have to apply the changes directly to your view model (if the changes are local), or you'll have to implement a diffing algorithm.

Comment: @Dennis Can't you manually raise the PropertyChanged event? `model = ordersServer.SaveOrder(model); RaisePropertyChanged("Model");`

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to create update batch/stored procedure that not only updates/inserts/deletes data but also queries the database for the new data.

When calling this batch you receive the new values and will be able to update the model and ViewModel accordingly.

Of course, simply re-querying the database for all the data is easier but might cost too much bandwidth and/or processing time.

Comment: the question is not "how to get identity/calculated values from database".

Comment: You can use the same mechanism from Model to ViewModels.